# Disabling flow for node_modules in a React Native project?

Tags: react-native

I'm getting the error:

> SyntaxError /node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/polyfill/Blob.js:
>   Type annotations must come before default assignments, e.g. instead of
>   `age = 25:number` use `age:number = 25` (227:50)

I'm assuming this has something to do with flow. But it seems that having flow check node_modules -- code you don't control -- is a bad idea to begin with. How do I go about disabling it for the whole `node_modules` dir?

I've tried adding `.*/node_modules/.*` under the `[ignore]` header in `.flowconfig`, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This pull request solves the same issue for `react-native-viewpager`: https://github.com/race604/react-native-viewpager/pull/97

You can copy that fix over to `react-native-fetch-blob` if you want to resolve your issue.

Comment: Oh, it seems like it's also been fixed in `react-native-fetch-blob`: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/134

Comment: Ha! Yes, that was me who posted the issue on github. Just linked to it as an answer when I saw your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the issue in git as well, and wkh237 went and fixed the problem. Use version 0.9.5-beta.4 or above and everything works.

You can see the github issue here: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/134